# forEach on querySelectorAll not working in recent Microsoft browsers

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, foreach, microsoft-edge

I am making a script for choices about a product (colors etc), which works in every browser except for *Internet Explorer* (11) & *Edge*.

I put the choices of each parameter in a array and apply a function to them with the `array.forEach()` method.

Example for the color parameter:

```
var color_btns = document.querySelectorAll('#color > p');
color_btns.forEach(function(color) {
    color.onclick = function () {
        color_btns.forEach(function(element) {
            if (element.classList.contains('selected')) {
                element.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        });
        color.classList.add('selected');
        document.querySelector('#f_color').value = color.dataset.id;
    };
});
```

I get the following output in the console of both *IE* & *Edge*:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

After searching about the issue, I learnt that this function should be [supported by IE 9 and newer](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach#compat-desktop). I tried to define the function by myself without success. When I log the function it is defined as a function (with "`[native code]`" inside).

I replaced every `.forEach` by a `for` and it's working pretty well,

- but how can I make it work ?
- Is there a specific usage of the `forEach()` for *Internet Explorer* & *Edge* ?

I thought it was `Array.prototype.forEach` and that recent versions of IE (and all versions of Edge) had it...?

Comment: `color_btns` is not an array but a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) - _"[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll): Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)."_

Comment: Oh right, it explains why it doesn't work, `NodeList.foreach` isn't supported in *Internet Explorer* ! Thanks @Andreas

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Most DOM methods and collection properties aren't actually arrays, they're collections:

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (a snapshot of matching elements as of when you call it).
- [`getElementsByTagName`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbytagname), [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbytagnamens), [`getElementsByClassName`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname), and the [`children`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-children) property on a [`ParentNode`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode) (Elements are parent nodes) return **live** `HTMLCollection` instances (if you change the DOM, that change is reflected live in the collection).
- [`getElementsByName`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyname) returns a **live** `NodeList` (not a snapshot).

`NodeList` only recently got `forEach` (and `keys` and a couple of other array methods). `HTMLCollection` didn't and won't; it turned out adding them would break too much code on the web.

Both `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection` are *iterable*, though, meaning that you can loop through them with `for-of`, expand them into an array via spread (`[...theCollection]`), etc. But if you're running on a browser where `NodeList` doesn't have `forEach`, it's probably too old to have any ES2015+ features like `for-of` or iteration.

Since `NodeList` is specified to have `forEach`, you can safely polyfill it, and it's *really* easy to do:

```
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    // Yes, there's really no need for `Object.defineProperty` here
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Direct assignment is fine in this case, because `enumerable`, `configurable`, and `writable` should all be `true` and it's a value property. (`enumerable` being `true` surprised me, but that's how it's defined natively on Chrome/Chromium/Edge/Etc., Firefox, the old Legacy Edge, and Safari).

In your own code, you can do that with `HTMLCollection` as well if you want, just beware that if you're using some old DOM libs like MooTools or YUI or some such, they may be confused if you add `forEach` to `HTMLCollection`.

---

As I said before, `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection` are both specified to be iterable (because of [this Web IDL rule](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#define-the-iteration-methods)¹). If you run into a browser that has ES2015+ features but *doesn't* make the collections iterable for some reason, you can polyfill that, too:

```
if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.iterator && typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator]) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, Symbol.iterator, {
        value: Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator],
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}
```

(And the same for `HTMLCollection`.)

Here's a live example using both, try this on (for instance) IE11 (although it will only demonstrate `forEach`), on which `NodeList` doesn't have these features natively:

```js
// Using only ES5 features so this runs on IE11
function log() {
    if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console.log) {
        console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
}
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype) {
    // forEach
    if (!NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
        // Yes, there's really no need for `Object.defineProperty` here
        console.log("Added forEach");
        NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    }
    // Iterability - won't happen on IE11 because it doesn't have Symbol
    if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.iterator && !NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator]) {
        console.log("Added Symbol.iterator");
        Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, Symbol.iterator, {
            value: Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator],
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}

log("Testing forEach");
document.querySelectorAll(".container div").forEach(function(div) {
    var html = div.innerHTML;
    div.innerHTML = html[0].toUpperCase() + html.substring(1).toLowerCase();
});

// Iterable
if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.iterator) {
    // Using eval here to avoid causing syntax errors on IE11
    log("Testing iterability");
    eval(
        'for (const div of document.querySelectorAll(".container div")) { ' +
        '    div.style.color = "blue"; ' +
        '}'
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
</div>
```

---

¹ It's confusing, because `HTMLCollection` is iterable but it **isn't** marked with the [`iterable` declaration](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-iterable), which bizarrely in the JavaScript DOM bindings **doesn't** mean that something is iterable, it means that it has `forEach`, `entries`, `keys`, `values`, **and** it's iterable. But `HTMLCollection`, which isn't marked with the `iterable` declaration, is still iterable. Instead, it's iterable because of [this Web IDL rule](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#define-the-iteration-methods) as mentioned earlier.

Comment: @wOxxOm - True. This was focussed on `forEach`, and in practice an environment that supports features that use iterability (like `for-of`) is likely to already provide iterability on `NodeList`, but I've added it above. Note that direct assignment doesn't replicate the native property descriptor, you need to use `Object.defineProperty`.

Answer (score 7):

OK, let's start from here, in JavaScript,  we have some cases which we call it **Array-like**, means even it looks like an array, it's not a real array...

For example **arguments** in function or in your case **Nodelist**...

Even All modern browsers understand which you'de like to change it to Array and work well, in IE and some other browsers it's not supported using array functions on Nodelist for example...

So if you supporting broad range of browsers, it's better to convert them to an array before doing any activity on them...

There are few ways to convert **Array-like** values to real **Array**...

One widely used in ES5 is this structure:

**Array.prototype.slice.call(YourNodeList);**

So you can do:

```
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var allRealDivsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(allDivs);
```

But if you using ES6, there are even neater ways to do it, just make sure you convert them to ES5 using babel for example as those old browsers which not supporting looping over array-like, won't support ES6 as well for sure...

Two very common ways to do them are:

**1) Using Array.from**

```
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
const allRealDivsArray = Array.from(allDivs);
```

**2) Using [...Array]**

```
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
const allRealDivsArray = [...allDivs];
```

Answer (score 2):

While it may look like an array, it's actually a NodeList which doesn't have the same features as an array.
Use a for loop instead

```
color_btns = document.querySelectorAll('#color > p'); 

for (var i = 0; i < color_btns.length; i++) {
    color_btns[i].onclick = function () { 
        for (var j = 0; j < color_btns.length; j++) {
            if(color_btns[j].classList.contains('selected')) { 
                color_btns[j].classList.remove('selected');
            }
        }
    color_btns[i].classList.add('selected'); 
    document.querySelector('#f_color').value = color_btns[i].dataset.id;
    };
}
```

Comment: I already use a `for` loop instead and yes it is still a good classic alternative. Thanks !

Comment: Pain, I know haha. Have a look at the answer from TJ Crowder for a polyfill to get it working anyway :)

Comment: I did, thanks @jERCle :)
By the way as @T.J.Crowder wrote you forgot to convert the 1st `forEach` hehe

Comment: Yeap, I missed that one. Sorry! Was in the middle of getting the kids too bed

Comment: I am, however, having a similar pain with IE11 at work regardless of the fact it should be available from IE9 up. Even as per Microsoft's docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/foreach-method-array-javascript

Comment: @jERCle: Probably the page is in (In)Compatibility Mode, where IE hobbles itself and pretends to be IE8 or even IE7. (In)Compatibility Mode is enabled by default on intranets, for instance.