# Javascript - Selecting elements and setting property based on phrase contained in ID

Tags: javascript

I have a number of field names that take the following format: 'Field1_ro', 'Field2_ro', 'Field3_ro'...

Is there a way I can set all fields that contain 'ro' to read only instead of using the following line everytime?

```
document.getElementById('Field1_ro').readOnly = true;
document.getElementById('Field2_ro').readOnly = true;
document.getElementById('Field3_ro').readOnly = true;
```

Comment: you can read this if you can use jQuery

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: @Sirmyself: That's jQuery, and *contains* rather than suffix. (Not that there may not be a dupetarget for this, there may be.)

Comment: @rlemon: That's *prefix*, not *suffix*.

Comment: prefix, suffix or contains are different jquery selector operators that pretty much do the same since they work the same. Asker here did definetly not do the most basic researches so I gave him some hints in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [*attribute-ends-with* selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings) on the `id` attribute, `[id$=_ro]` with `querySelectorAll`, and loop on the result:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id$=_ro]").forEach(function(element) {
    element.readOnly = true;
});
```

That said, giving them a common class and using a class selector would be more typical. Or, ideally, adding the `readonly` attribute when they're defined instead of afterward. :-)

---

Note: The `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` only got `forEach` relatively recently, but you can easily polyfill it on older browsers, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929259/157247) for an example of doing so.

Comment: Do you know if this is compatible with IE 11?

Comment: @peterbonar: Yes, IE11 has `querySelectorAll` (even IE8 did). You'll need the polyfill I mention above, though. (It's trivial.)

Comment: Where do I add the code that is in this answer? The polyfill answer. :)

Comment: @peterbonar: Anywhere where it's run before you try to use `forEach` on the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll`. (Or don't do the polyfill and just use `for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) { list[i].readOnly = true; }`)

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks :)