# How to insert <tr> after every <tr> with pure JS

Tags: javascript, insert, tr

I would like to insert new `<tr>` after every existing `<tr>`. 
My function :

```
var element = document.querySelector('tr.cart-item');
var newElement = document.createElement('tr');
newElement.className = "tr-spacer";
var elementParent = element.parentNode;
elementParent.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
```

but it insert `<tr>` only after first `<tr>`, is it possible insert `<tr>` after every existing `<tr>`?
I also tried `querySelectorAll` or `insertRow` but it does not seem to work.
Thanks you

Comment: Use `.querySelectorAll()` instead of `.querySelector()` ?

Comment: This sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Whatever you want to do with "spacer" `tr`s, you probably want to do with CSS instead. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine with `querySelectorAll`. You didn't show your code trying to use that, but you'd have a loop:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('tr.cart-item');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    var element = list[i];
    var newElement = document.createElement('tr');
    newElement.className = "tr-spacer";
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
}
```

or on modern browsers (or with a polyfill, which is trivial; more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259)):

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr.cart-item').forEach(function(element) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('tr');
    newElement.className = "tr-spacer";
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
});
```

or (again, modern browsers):

```
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('tr.cart-item') {
    const newElement = document.createElement('tr');
    newElement.className = "tr-spacer";
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: *(Sigh, editing error: If you don't see `querySelectorAll` in the code blocks above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: I had to do some typo, cause Ive tried your first example, but it didnt work. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to loop through your `<tr>` tags.

First select them all using `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

Then loop through them and add a new one after each.

---

As *@T.J. Crowder* pointed out in the comments, notice how there's an added step to check if the current `<tr>` has a next sibling by checking if `nextElementSibling` is truthy.

```js
let lines = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

for(let line of lines){
  let newLine = document.createElement('tr');
  newLine.innerText = 'Inserted';
  if(line.nextElementSibling) line.parentNode.insertBefore(newLine, line.nextElementSibling);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all elements matching selector using `querySelectorAll` and then either in naked `for` loop or using `Array.prototype.forEach` create ad insert new `tr` after each element:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('tr.cart-item'), function (element) {
  var newElement = document.createElement('tr');
  newElement.className = "tr-spacer";
  element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="cart-item">
    <td>First</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cart-item">
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cart-item">
    <td>Third</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```