# How to efficiently store DOM elements in association with their corresponding objects?

Tags: javascript, html

I am delegating a key input event from the `document` onto the several `textarea`s on the page. Because the operations I need to perform on the key input are complex, repetitive, and tied to the text contents of that textarea - I find it better to cache that information in a `TextareaState` object (something like `{wasChanged: true, penultimateTextContents: "string", etc.}`) for each `<textarea>`. It would also make sense to store this object permanently, rather than recomputing it every time an input event was fired (recomputing would erase the important previous results anyway).

At first I thought of using a key-value pair object, but DOM elements cannot be substituted as object keys. I could instead try to generate a [unique CSS selector](https://github.com/ericclemmons/unique-selector) for each DOM element and then use that selector as the object key, but this approach seems very expensive.

My third and final approach was to use two arrays (`var textareaElements = [], TextareaStateObjects = []`) and then every time an input handler was fired, I could do `TextareaStateObjects[textareaElements.indexOf(event.target)]` to get the corresponding cached object. However, that still seems pretty expensive, considering that `.indexOf` runs at every input event, and is going to be very costly for larger array lengths.

Is there a more efficient solution here?

Comment: This may be slightly irrelevant but this sounds like a perfect use case for an observables library like Knockout.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a more efficient solution here?

Yes, either of your first two solutions. :-) Details:

> At first I thought of using a key-value pair object, but DOM elements cannot be substituted as object keys.

That's true, but they can be [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object keys. They can even be [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) object keys if you need to prevent the `Map` from keeping the element in memory.

You do need to target environments that have `Map` and `WeakMap` (all current major ones do), although there are some really powerful polyfills out there doing cool things to emulate `Map` behavior in a clever, well-performing way.

Example:

```js
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    // Yes, there's really no need for `Object.defineProperty` here
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}

const map = new WeakMap();
document.querySelectorAll("textarea").forEach((element, index) => {
  ++index;
  map.set(element, {name: "TextArea #" + index});
});

document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const entry = map.get(event.target);
  if (entry) {
    console.log("The name for the textarea you clicked is " + entry.name);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>Click in each of these text areas:</div>
<textarea>one</textarea>
<textarea>two</textarea>
```

> I could instead try to generate a unique CSS selector for each DOM element and then use that selector as the object key, but this approach seems very expensive.

It isn't if you use `id` for that: Give yourself a unique prefix and then following it with an ever-increasing number. (And if you need to go from the ID to the element, `getElementById` is **blindingly** fast.)

Example:

```js
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    // Yes, there's really no need for `Object.defineProperty` here
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}

let nextIdNum = 1;
const pseudoMap = Object.create(null);
document.querySelectorAll("textarea").forEach((element, index) => {
  if (!element.id) {
    element.id = "__x_" + nextIdNum++;
  }
  ++index;
  pseudoMap[element.id] = {name: "TextArea #" + index};
});

document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const entry = pseudoMap[event.target.id];
  if (entry) {
    console.log("The name for the textarea you clicked is " + entry.name);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>Click in each of these text areas:</div>
<textarea>one</textarea>
<textarea>two</textarea>
```

If you use `id` for other purposes, it can be a `data-*` attribute instead. (And if you need to go from the `data-*` attribute value to the element, `querySelector` on a `data-*` attribute isn't all that expensive.)

Example:

```js
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    // Yes, there's really no need for `Object.defineProperty` here
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}

let nextIdNum = 1;
const pseudoMap = Object.create(null);
document.querySelectorAll("textarea").forEach((element, index) => {
  const id = "__x_" + nextIdNum++;
  element.setAttribute("data-id", id);
  pseudoMap[id] = {name: "TextArea #" + index};
});

document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const entry = pseudoMap[event.target.getAttribute("data-id")];
  if (entry) {
    console.log("The name for the textarea you clicked is " + entry.name);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>Click in each of these text areas:</div>
<textarea>one</textarea>
<textarea>two</textarea>
```

Comment: Is there really an advantage to `element.setAttribute("data-id", id);` as compared to the shorter `element.dataset.id = id;`?

Comment: @GaurangTandon - Broader support ([link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)), but even IE11 had `dataset` so...not really, unless you need to support IE8 (which some people do, poor sods). :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a unique id on each input and then create an array where the index of each key is used to access the cached version of your data.

```
var cachedData=[];
cachedData[someElement.id] = someValue;
```

This would be an O(1) operation to read/write the indexed value.

Comment: Hmm, good solution. I would still need to generate the IDs though, I guess `const getRandomID => "APP" + Math.random();` would work for that. Would it? || Ah, maybe the ever-increasing number would work better as suggested by Crowder.

Comment: If the elements are not dynamicaly added/removed from the dom you can even do a simple forEach on the elements and assigne their index as the key, this would mean that you do not even need to set a key or generate anything. Only if nothing messes up your dom thought, this is not a good idea in general .. too fragile tie between obejcts

Comment: I agree. My input elements are dynamic though :/