# Does not capture the second form attribute name with getAttribute('name');

Tags: javascript

I'm just looking at the JavaScript events for a project, but there is something I cannot find the reason why it does not work or does not show the event with getAttribute('name') when supposedly if there is the second   like this:

```
<form name='otherRegistration'>
    <input type="email"></input> 
    <button class="btn btn-safe col-xs-6"></button>
</form>

<form name='registration'>
    <button class="btn btn-security col-xs-6"></button>
</form>
```

The question is that if it catches the name attribute of the first form name `otherRegistration` but does not capture the name of the second form `registration` which is weird and I don't have an idea why this happens, I have checked carefully and can not find the reason.

Once having the attribute name of the form does not enter the if which I do not understand because, if it revises with typeof and returns string

I would appreciate if you help me understand why and what is the solution, here the code:

```
function userSessionSubmit() {

    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var formName = '';

    form.addEventListener('click', function () {
        formName = form.getAttribute('name');

        console.log(formName);

        switch (formName) {
            case 'otherRegistration':
                alert('TRIGGER OTHER'); //works 
                break;
            case 'registration':
                alert('TRIGGER REGIS'); //does not work...
                break;
            default:
                alert('nothing');
                break;
        }
    });
};

userSessionSubmit();
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelector(selector)` selects one element - the first one found on the page.

To select multiple elements with one query you should use `document.querySelectorAll(selector)` and assign it to a variable.

Example code:

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form'); // select all forms on the page
Array.prototype.forEach.call(forms, (form) => {
   form.addEventListener('click', listenerFunc); // add on click listener to every form
}); // iterate trough found elements
```

**Edit:**

You should consider using unanonymous functions in your listeners - you can not use `removeEventListener()` on anonymous functions.

Comment: Worth noting that on modern browsers, the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` has its own built-in `forEach` method, which is [easily polyfilled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259) for older browsers. So there isn't really any need for `Array.prototype.forEach.call` anymore.

Comment: Right. You can also use `Object.values` for that. It all works.

Comment: Um, huh? `Object.values` would be a very strange choice for the above. Whereas `document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach(...)` is much simpler and more direct.

Comment: It is, I agree with you 100%. I just saying there are options - some better than others.