# indexOf is not a fuction, can't find index of element in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have an array that contains HTML elements(I filled it with `querySelectorAll()`),  and I'm trying to find the index of an element in that array but the console is giving the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: rows.indexOf is not a function

I used this to fill the array with the needed HTML elements:

`rows = document.querySelectorAll("#selectableTableBody > tr");`

and this to find the index:

`document.getElementById("tableItem_10087528").onclick = function (e) {
console.log(rows.indexOf(this));
}`

and here is an image of my test in the console(which doesn't make sense):
[image: image captured from Chrome's console]

it's worth noting that these elements are generated with javascript and then put in the array using `querySelectorAll()`
here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Elias47/xqt0sg8c/) if you want to check the whole thing

Comment: You're running fillSelect several times before setting rows at the very last line, no? So the rows would be undefined at that point.

Comment: that is because the result is not an array - but a node list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an array that contains HTML elements(I filled it with querySelectorAll())

No, you don't, which is the problem. :-) `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) | [spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist)), not an array.

You can convert it into an array in several ways:

```
rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(/*...*/));
```

or (in up-to-date environments where `NodeList` is iterable):

```
rows = [...document.querySelectorAll(/*...*/)];
```

or in old environments:

```
rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(/*...*/));
```

---

Re iterability: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259) discusses polyfilling `NodeList` iterability on platforms where arrays are iterable (either natively or thanks to a polyfill) but `NodeList` isn't (yet).

Comment: Take a look at the MDN page about `NodeList`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Not you, but @Elias, my comment were anterior to your edits that add the link to the documentation ;-)

Comment: @enguerran - Ah, I understand now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: rows.indexOf is not a function

You get this error because you are calling `.indexOf()` over a `nodeList` and not an `array`, because [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will return a `nodeList` and not an `array`.

You can get an `array` from this `nodeList/collection` using **[`Array.from()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**:

```
rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#selectableTableBody > tr"));
```

**Demo:**

This is your  [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqt0sg8c/2/).

Answer (score 1):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array.

You need to use

```js
rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#selectableTableBody > tr"));
```

Answer (score 1):

That is bacause the return of querySelectorAll() is an array like object (object with length property) not an array. you need to convert it to array using Array.from(rows).