# replace all elements belonging to a specific class

Tags: javascript

I was trying to develop an embedded widget. User would include an `anchor` tag and a javascript in their page, and it would render the content. Similar to embedded tweets.

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/user/13"
        target="_blank"
        class="my-widget" 
        data-widget-type="profile" 
        data-widget-identifier="id" 
        data-identifier-value="13"
   >Sayantan Das</a>
</div>
<script src="//localhost/my-widget/js/widget.js" async ></script>
```

And from `widget.js`, i would get all the elements with `class="my-widget"` and replace with an `iframe`.

**widgets.js**

```
!function(global, document) {
    global.MyWidgets = global.MyWidgets || {};

    for(let widgets = document.getElementsByClassName('my-widget'), i = 0; i < widgets.length; i++) {
        console.log(widgets)
        let element = widgets[i];
        let span = document.createElement('span');

        span.innerHTML = "Changed from widget " + i;
        element.parentNode.appendChild(span);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }

}(window, document);
```

The problem is , when I remove the element the loop also runs for a shorter number. for example, if there are two elements with class `my-widget`, after first time the loop runs and one element is removed and the loop runs only once. How do I replace all the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `getElementsByClassName` returns a **live** `HTMLCollection`; when you remove the `class="my-widget"` element from the DOM, it's also removed from the collection.

Either work backward through the collection (so you're removing from the end, which doesn't affect the ones before it), or use `querySelectorAll(".my-widget")` instead, which returns a snapshot `NodeList`, not a live `HTMLCollection`.

Working backward:

```
for(let widgets = document.getElementsByClassName('my-widget'), i = widgets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Using qSA instead:

```
for(let widgets = document.querySelectorAll('.my-widget'), i = 0; i < widgets.length; i++) {
```

or if you don't need `i` (you seem only to be using it to get the element and for demo purposes), you can use `for-of` with `NodeList`s now (on most platforms; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259) has a polyfill for others):

```
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.my-widget')) {
    // ...and remove the `let element = ...` line
```

Comment: thank you, i did not know that. and `querySelectorAll` worked. can you explain what you meant by **Either work backward through the collection** though?

Comment: @SayantanDas - You commented as I was demonstrating. Basically: `i = widgets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--`.

Answer (score 0):

use `document.querySelectorAll` to the length of the widgets

Comment: Please edit your answer and give to it a little bit more heart and work ;) Answer is ok, but a bit short and no good example.