# How do I choose the selected "<option>" of an HTML "<select>" by it's text content in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have the following HTML `<select>` element:

```
<select id="account" class="form-control" name="account">
  <option value="USFSDsdfsFLIJSD656FKLLS5admFOWEJF0SOF">5265241</option>
  <option value="LDSOJFksdfo52slkdfjskdfooojoijoijoj56">6524125</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to make the selected option the `<option>` tag with the text content of `6524125`.

I've tried using the following code to do so:

```
document.getElementById("account").value = "6524125";
```

Although this didn't work, how can I set the value of this `<select>` element by text?

**UPDATE:** Yes, I am using jQuery and here is my code so far:

```
$("option:contains('6524125')").prop("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through the `option` elements in the `select` to find a match, for instance:

```js
const text = "6524125";
const options = document.getElementById("account").options;
for (let n = 0; n < options.length; ++n) {
    const option = options[n];
    if (option.text === text) {
        option.selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="account" class="form-control" name="account">
    <option value="USFSDsdfsFLIJSD656FKLLS5admFOWEJF0SOF">5265241</option>
    <option value="LDSOJFksdfo52slkdfjskdfooojoijoijoj56">6524125</option>
</select>
```

In some modern environments `options` is iterable, so you can do it more concisely:

```js
const text = "6524125";
for (const option of document.getElementById("account").options) {
    if (option.text === text) {
        option.selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="account" class="form-control" name="account">
    <option value="USFSDsdfsFLIJSD656FKLLS5admFOWEJF0SOF">5265241</option>
    <option value="LDSOJFksdfo52slkdfjskdfooojoijoijoj56">6524125</option>
</select>
```

The specification doesn't require `options` to be iterable, though (it's an `HTMLOptionsCollection`, which inherits from [`HTMLCollection`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection), which unlike `NodeList` is not iterable). If you're doing this in your own app or page (not a library), you can make `HTMLCollection` iterable as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259).

Comment: thanks for your response quotes

$('option:contains("6524125")').prop('selected', true);

Comment: @ray - Well, since nothing in your question suggested or said you were using jQuery, naturally I didn't use jQuery in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to loop through your elements and set the `selected` property of that element to true if its `textContent` matches a specified value, like this:

```js
const text = "6524125";
[...document.getElementsByTagName("option")].forEach(element => {
  if (element.textContent === text) {
    element.selected = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="account" class="form-control" name="account">
  <option value="USFSDsdfsFLIJSD656FKLLS5admFOWEJF0SOF">5265241</option>
  <option value="LDSOJFksdfo52slkdfjskdfooojoijoijoj56">6524125</option>
</select>
```

Another method is to set the target `option` element's `selected` attribute manually, this prevents you from having to write more code than you need to.

In other words, you can replace ~6 lines of JavaScript with a single HTML attribute.

This is also great if you only want to [set the default value for an HTML "<select>" element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518011/10415695).

For example:

```html
<select id="account" class="form-control" name="account">
  <option value="USFSDsdfsFLIJSD656FKLLS5admFOWEJF0SOF">5265241</option>
  <option value="LDSOJFksdfo52slkdfjskdfooojoijoijoj56" selected="selected">6524125</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:** I just saw that you included a jQuery snippet in [comments section of T.J. Crowder's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240323/10415695).

If you are using jQuery then you can use the [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and the [`jQuery.fn.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to select the target option and set it's `selected` attribute:

```js
$("option:contains('6524125')").attr("selected", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="account" class="form-control" name="account">
  <option value="USFSDsdfsFLIJSD656FKLLS5admFOWEJF0SOF">5265241</option>
  <option value="LDSOJFksdfo52slkdfjskdfooojoijoijoj56" selected="selected">6524125</option>
</select>
```

If you'd like to remove the `selected` attributes from the target element's siblings, then you'd use the [`jQuery.fn.siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [`jQuery.fn.removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) methods, like this:

```
$("option:contains('6524125')").attr("selected", true).siblings().removeAttr("selected");
```

**NOTE:** for more information on the `forEach` method, [visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/10415695).

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your response quotes

Comment: Anytime, just let me know if it doesn't work.