# Changing text values of <li> with less than 3 characters

Tags: javascript

I'm making a list for the new football season where I want to plugin the results for each played round and display it in a list. I want to change the value of all "li" with less than 3 characters and instead display

"To be played"

I've tried coding a loop that looks through all elements with the tagName "li" and if the element has less than three characters, it replaces its innerHTML with "To be played".

```
<div>
  <ul id="allResults">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
var parentGame = document.getElementById("allResults");
var listGames = parentGame.getElementsByTagName("li");
var listGamesLength = listGames.length;
for (var i = 0; i < listGamesLength; i++) {
  if (listGamesLength[i] < 3) {
    listGames[i].innerHTML = "To be played";
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm quite sure that there is a lot of things wrong with my code, but I would like to know how to fix it - Or rewrite it in case it's completely wrong.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: When you are getting those `li` elements, check `.innerHTML.length` for the true length inside of `li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you didn't close the quote:

```
<ul id="allResults">
```

You need to get the `innerText` to get the value and number of the `li` element instead of the exact element. So your code would be like this:

```
listGames[i].innerText < 3
```

And you can convert it to `int` to compare it correctly. So the result is:

```
parseInt(listGames[i].innerText) < 3
```

By the way you were setting the element that was not defined. so I changed it to this:

```
listGames[i].innerHTML = "To be played";
```

---

The **final code** would be like below:

```js
var parentGame = document.getElementById("allResults");
var listGames = parentGame.getElementsByTagName("li");
var listGamesLength = listGames.length;
for (var i = 0; i < listGamesLength; i++) {
  if (parseInt(listGames[i].innerText) < 3) {
    listGames[i].innerHTML = "To be played";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="allResults">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this as well!

Comment: it was my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You missed a closing `"` on the `id` attribute. You could also use `querySelectorAll` to get each `li` element and lessen the amount of queries to the DOM. The biggest miss was that you were checking `listGames.length` which gives you the amount of `li` elements, not the amount of characters of each element. The correct way would be to check `innerHTML.length` for said element.

Maybe something like this? I changed the last one to 100 to better illustrate the result.

```js
var listGames = document.querySelectorAll("#allResults li");
listGames.forEach(game => {
  if (game.innerHTML.length < 3) {
    game.innerHTML = "To be played";
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="allResults">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>100</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your lines:

```
 if (listGamesLength[i] < 3) {
   howManyNodes[i].innerHTML = "To be played";
 }
```

Probably ought to be:

```
 if (listGames[i].innerHTML.length < 3) {
     listGames[i].innerHTML = "To be played";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (listGamesLength[i] < 3) {` checks the length of the list against the number `3`, not the length of the content of any entry in the list. For that you want:

```
if (listGames[i].textContent.length < 3) {
```

Aside from that, your code is okay other than using `howManyNodes` rather than `listGames`. But you can make it much simpler:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#allResults li").forEach(li => {
    if (li.textContent.length < 3) {
        li.textContent = "To be played";
    }
});
```

The `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` is specified to have a `forEach` method (now, it didn't used to be). If you need to support older environments where it may not have it yet, you can use [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259) to deal with it. In those environments, you'd probably need a traditional function instead of an arrow function as well, so:

```
// (After applying the polyfill to `NodeList.prototype`)
document.querySelectorAll("#allResults li").forEach(function(li) {
    if (li.textContent.length < 3) {
        li.textContent = "To be played";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've never met this querySelectorAll function. You just define the id with a hashtag before?  I'll try playing around with your snippet to see how it functions!

Comment: @noroma - `querySelectorAll` lets you use any valid CSS selector to get a `NodeList` of matching elements in the DOM. If you use it on `document` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)), it gets all of them. If you use it on an element instead ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)), it only searches within the element's tree. So yes, since you select IDs using `#`, that's why I have `#` in the example above.