# How to remove one css class from div container with multiple elements and classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get all elements which belong to two specific different classes and remove and add these classes seperately from these elements. I tried:

```
.concealed {
  display: none;
}
.slide {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

`// <div class="slide concealed">myText</div><br>
<div class="slide"><div class="concealed">myText</div></div><br>
<div class="slide"><div class="concealed">myText_2</div></div><br>
<div class="slide"><div class="concealed">myText_3</div></div><br>`

```
    // var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
    // var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide, .concealed');
       var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide concealed');

slides[0].classList.remove("concealed");
```

As you can see I tried several ways to achieve this but I can only remove and add "concealed" when I do *var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('concealed');* . When doing *getElementsByClassName* with multiple classnames it seems to miss out *concealed* and only get *slide*. E.g. doing *slides[0].classList.remove("concealed");* after *document.getElementsByClassName('slide concealed');* has no effect.

I am sure I am missing something, this can't that hard to implement. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: *"...and remove and add these classes seperately from these elements..."* I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're trying to do with the elements. Your commented-out code using `querySelectorAll` should work, but it seems like it didn't. Can you give us more information on that?

Comment: after trying `var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide, .concealed');` I noticed that `slides.length`was the double count of my elements and assumed that this can't be right. it seems i need to read about NodeList handling ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`getElementsByClassName`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) is a **live** `HTMLCollection`. When an element no longer matches (because you've removed the class), it's removed from the collection:

```js
const list = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
console.log(list.length);       // 2
console.log(list[0].innerHTML); // "A"
list[0].classList.remove("example");
console.log(list.length);       // 1
console.log(list[0].innerHTML); // "B"
```

```html
<div class="example">A</div>
<div class="example">B</div>
```

This means that if you're doing a loop and operate on the first entry, then increment your index, you'll miss what used to be the second entry because it's the first entry now.

A couple of ways to fix that:

1. Loop backward, or
2. Convert the `HTMLCollection` into an array before starting, or
3. Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-queryselectorall) to get a **snapshot** `NodeList` instead, so that the lists contents don't change while you're updating.

Here's an example removing the classes `red` and `bold` from a series of elements using `querySelectorAll` so the `NodeList` is static:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll(".red, .bold");
    for (let n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
        list[n].classList.remove("red");
        list[n].classList.remove("bold");
    }
}, 800);
```

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">red 1</div>
<div class="bold">bold 1</div>
<div class="red bold">red 2 and bold 2</div>
<div class="bold">bold 3</div>
<div class="bold">bold 4</div>
```

---

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929259/157247): `NodeList` is now officially *iterable*, meaning you should be able to use a `for-of` loop on it. That answer shows how to polyfill that on slightly-older environments that haven't implemented it yet. It also shows how to add iterability to `HTMLCollection` (but note that `HTMLCollection` is **not** specified to be iterable).

Comment: The problem was indeed that `getElementsByClassName` is a live collection and not a snapshot. Thank you!