# Convert for loop to ES6 for of loop

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, callback, nodelist

I would like to convert this piece of code to ES-6. So the for loop in the first example I used needs to be a for of loop. What happens is in the second version that the percentage calculation works just as expected as i can see in the console but it doesn't show in the UI. The older, first method works fine. How come?

```
// This one works fine
displayPercentages: function(percentages) {

          var fields = 
document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.expensesPercLabel);

          var nodeListForEach = function(list, callback) {   
            for(var i = 0; i < list.length ; i++) {
                console.log(list[i], i)
                callback(list[i], i)          
            }
        }; 

             nodeListForEach(fields, function(el, index){
              if(percentages[index] > 0){
                 el.textContent = percentages[index] + '%'
             }else{
                el.textContent = '---';
             }

          });
      },


 // Second version has a problem showing percentages in the UI

  displayPercentages: function(percentages) {       

  var fields = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.expensesPercLabel);

  var nodeListForEach = function(list, callback) {
  for(let [el, index] of list.entries()) {
      console.log(el, index)
      callback(el, index)
    }
 }; 

 nodeListForEach(fields, function(el, index){
  if(percentages[index] > 0){
      el.textContent = percentages[index] + '%'
  }else{
      el.textContent = '---';
  }

 });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `for` loop's body uses the index, you're probably best off sticking with a `for` loop, not switching to `for-of`.

You *can* switch to `for-of` (on browsers that have implemented making `NodeList` iterable, or [if you polyfill it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259), or by using `Array.from`) by spreading the `NodeList` out into an array (or using `Array.from` to create an array) and then using `Array.prototype.entries`, which gives you an an iterator where each value iterated is an `[index, value]` array:

```
displayPercentages: function(percentages) {
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.expensesPercLabel);
  for (const [index, el] of [...fields].entries()) {
    if (percentages[index] > 0) {
      el.textContent = percentages[index] + '%'
    } else {
      el.textContent = '---';
    }
  }
}
```

(Note that [`Array.prototype.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) is fairly new and may need polyfilling.)

**But**: That's really quite indirect compared to just using a `for` loop:

```
displayPercentages: function(percentages) {
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.expensesPercLabel);
  for (let index = 0; index < fields.length; ++index) {
    const el = fields[index];
    if (percentages[index] > 0) {
      el.textContent = percentages[index] + '%'
    } else {
      el.textContent = '---';
    }
  }
}
```

...or for that matter, using the `forEach` that is on `NodeList` now (which, again, you can [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259)):

```
displayPercentages: function(percentages) {
  document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.expensesPercLabel).forEach((el, index) => {
    if (percentages[index] > 0) {
      el.textContent = percentages[index] + '%'
    } else {
      el.textContent = '---';
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks T.J. for your help, various options here. Gonna try them out.