# How do i make my reset function work on my input element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, input

I have a reset function, which selects the id of an input.

I have a button which fires the function when clicked.

Where am I going wrong here? I thought maybe it was because my input was not in a form, and that i would need to create a form and give it an id to reference. But that didn't work either.

I also tried using document.getElementById.("reset").reset();

This didn't work either.

im lost!

```
function clearInputs(){
document.getElementById("reset").value = "";
}
```

---

```
     <div class="container">

    <div class="cell-1" id="centerElement">
        <div id="cell-1-nest-l"></div>
        <div id="cell-2-nest-l"></div>
        <div id="cell-3-nest-l"></div>
        <div id="cell-4-nest-l"><h3>your name</h3></div>
        <div id="cell-5-nest-l"></div>
        <div id="cell-6-nest-l"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1" id="nameInput1" class="reset"></div>
```

```
    <div class="cell-2" id="centerElement" ><img onclick="getSum();" src="file:///Users/Nineborn/Downloads/My%20Post%20(5).png" alt=""></div>

    <div class="cell-3" id="centerElement" >
            <div id="cell-1-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-2-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-3-nest"><h3>their name</h3></div>
            <div id="cell-4-nest"></div>
            <div id="cell-5-nest"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1" id="nameInput2"></div>
            <div id="cell-6-nest"></div>


            </div>

    <div class="cell-4" id="result1">
        <input type="date" class="dateStyle1" id="dateInput1">
            </div>

    <div class="cell-5"><input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clearInputs();"></div>

    <div class="cell-6" id="result2"> 
        <input type="date" class="dateStyle2" id="dateInput2" placeholder="Their Bday">
            </div>
    <div class="cell-7"></div>

    <div class="cell-8"></div>

    <div class="cell-9"></div>
```

Comment: The "id" of the inputs are "nameInput1" and "nameInput1", not "reset".

Comment: Use: `<input type="reset" value="Reset">` this will reset all values inside your form tag.

Comment: right but there is no form tag. Also, im actually not being clear in this question, but I want a button which will delete ALL my inputs. I have two date inputs and two text inputs. I was just trying to figure out how to at LEAST get the button working on a single element before I tackled a way to select all of them.

Comment: Just wrap all your code inside your form tag. it will not change anything. and use  `<input type="reset" value="Reset">`

Comment: the thing is, my css is using the grid. So this particular input is in a nested grid item. Its in grid cell 1 of 9 cells. The thing is, I want to eventually select all the inputs (there are 4, two date inputs and two text inputs) and rest them using one button. SO an input type "reset" doesnt really work for me here, because it would only apply to one input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting to your code: If you want to reset the fields of a form to their initial values, you don't need to write any code at all. Just use an `input type="reset"` in the form:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

```html
<form>
<div class="container">

        <div class="cell-1" id="centerElement">
            <div id="cell-1-nest-l"></div>
            <div id="cell-2-nest-l"></div>
            <div id="cell-3-nest-l"></div>
            <div id="cell-4-nest-l"><h3>your name</h3></div>
            <div id="cell-5-nest-l"></div>
            <div id="cell-6-nest-l"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1 reset" id="nameInput1"></div>
           
  </div>

        <div class="cell-2" id="centerElement" ><img onclick="getSum();" src="file:///Users/Nineborn/Downloads/My%20Post%20(5).png" alt=""></div>

        <div class="cell-3" id="centerElement" >
                <div id="cell-1-nest"></div>
                <div id="cell-2-nest"></div>
                <div id="cell-3-nest"><h3>their name</h3></div>
                <div id="cell-4-nest"></div>
                <div id="cell-5-nest"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1" id="nameInput2"></div>
                <div id="cell-6-nest"></div>
                
            
                </div>

        <div class="cell-4" id="result1">
            <input type="date" class="dateStyle1" id="dateInput1">
                </div>
                
        <div class="cell-5"><input type="reset" value="Reset""></div>
                    
        <div class="cell-6" id="result2"> 
            <input type="date" class="dateStyle2" id="dateInput2" placeholder="Their Bday">
                </div>
        <div class="cell-7"></div>

        <div class="cell-8"></div>

        <div class="cell-9"></div>
            

</div>
</form>
```

---

But re your code:

Your `input`'s `id` is `nameInput1`, not `reset` (`reset` is its *class*). Either use that ID instead:

```
document.getElementById("nameInput1").value = "";
```

or use `querySelector` (if there will only ever be one) or `querySelectorAll` (if there will be more than one) with the class:

```
// If there will only ever be one
document.querySelector(".reset").value = "";

// If there will be more than one
document.querySelectorAll(".reset").forEach(function(input) {
    input.value = "";
});
```

If you're using that second option, you may need to polyfill `forEach` on older browsers; my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259) shows how.

Note that some of your elements have more than one `class=""` on them. You can't do that, all but the first one are ignored. If you want more than one class on an element, put all of the classes in a single `class=""` separated by spaces.

Here's an example of clearing multiple `input`s, all with the class `reset`:

```js
function clearInputs() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".reset").forEach(function(input) {
        input.value = "";
    });
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">

<div class="cell-1" id="centerElement">
    <div id="cell-1-nest-l"></div>
    <div id="cell-2-nest-l"></div>
    <div id="cell-3-nest-l"></div>
    <div id="cell-4-nest-l"><h3>your name</h3></div>
    <div id="cell-5-nest-l"></div>
    <div id="cell-6-nest-l"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1 reset" id="nameInput1"></div>
<div class="cell-2" id="centerElement" ><img onclick="getSum();" src="file:///Users/Nineborn/Downloads/My%20Post%20(5).png" alt=""></div>

<div class="cell-3" id="centerElement" >
        <div id="cell-1-nest"></div>
        <div id="cell-2-nest"></div>
        <div id="cell-3-nest"><h3>their name</h3></div>
        <div id="cell-4-nest"></div>
        <div id="cell-5-nest"><input type="text" class="nameStyle1 reset" id="nameInput2"></div>
        <div id="cell-6-nest"></div>


        </div>

<div class="cell-4" id="result1">
    <input type="date" class="dateStyle1 reset" id="dateInput1">
        </div>

<div class="cell-5"><input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clearInputs();"></div>

<div class="cell-6" id="result2"> 
    <input type="date" class="dateStyle2 reset" id="dateInput2" placeholder="Their Bday">
        </div>
<div class="cell-7"></div>

<div class="cell-8"></div>

<div class="cell-9"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for this, I corrected that earlier but it still doesn't work!

Comment: im going to try and rewrite this using a queryselctor all because i actually want this to work on all my inputs. In my HTML i have two date inputs and two text inputs.

Comment: @nineborn - [Yes, it does work](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/7ngfecm9/1/). And if you want to do all your inputs, see the "if there will be more than one" part of the answer.

Comment: haha ok im sure it does, im just trying to figure out where im going wrong. Im going to use a querySelectorAll("#reset") and add a class of "reset" to the html of that element and test it.

Comment: @nineborn - One problem is that you have `class=""` in more than one place within a tag, which doesn't work. I've noted that in my answer and added a running example.

Comment: woops didnt finish reading your comment. Ok so i need to keep them multiple classes within the class tag. doh. Let me try this.

Comment: thank you this finally worked. Thing i dont understand is, why do I use a forEach on a querySelectorAll? I thought querySelectorAll would select all the elements, and then passing in the .value would be sufficient. Why is it not? 

Also i dont understand the (input) argument inside the forEach function.

Would you mind clarifying all this for a newbie? Im trying to understand the thought process

Comment: Also, regarding the first part of your answer, regarding your advice to use a input type"reset" instead. Yes i realized that this would clear a form, but my inputs are 

#1 not in forms (should they be?) 

 #2 they are in different grid cells (DIV's) in a grid container. Unless I'm missing something, and i can write a simple input type "reset" and assign it to all my inputs across the grid...then i figured i needed to write a function instead.

Comment: @nineborn - `querySelectorAll` returns a list of matching elements. That list doesn't have a `value` property, the DOM doesn't have a set-based API (like jQuery does, for instance). To set the value of each input in the list of matching elements, you have to loop through it. `forEach` does that, it calls the callback you give it repeatedly, once for each element in the list, passing the list in as the first argument. The callback above accepts that argument as the named parameter `input`. So each time it's called (once per element), `input` refers to a different input in the list.

Comment: @nineborn - Re `type="reset"`: You can wrap a `form` around the entire grid. The inputs being in different cells in the grid isn't a problem. If you do that, beware of a gotcha on the `button` element (`button`, **not** `input type="button"`). The default `type` of `button` elements is `submit`, so they'll try to submit the form if they're in a `form`. When using `button` just as a button, you need `<button type="button" ...>`. But you're using `input type="button"` so you're okay.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. when i initially researched an answer for this, i swore i saw someone put a .value at the end of selecting an ID. Could you do the simple .value = "" at the end of other selectors? Say getElementById?

Comment: Also, what would do you think is better practice? Writing out the function we've built, or wrapping it in a form?

Comment: @nineborn - See the answer above, yes, you can use `.value` on the result of `getElementById` or `querySelector` because they return a **single** element (or `null` if none is found), not a list. `querySelectorAll`, `getElementsByTagName`, etc. return lists. I would use the reset functionality built into the browser rather than implementing it myself. Re best practices: It's not best practice touse `onclick` attributes and such. Use `addEventListener` or similar instead. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("reset") searches for an element with id="reset" which does not seem to exist, which is why nothing gets reset.

If your `<input>` is in a `<form>` you can use `<input type="reset">` to reset all form values (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_reset.asp)

You can try

```
document.getElementById("nameInput2").value = "";
```

and see that it would work on that specific element

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="cell-6-nest-l">
  <input type="text" class="nameStyle1" id="nameInput1" class="reset">
</div>
```

here class is reset and you are using `getElementById("reset")` which is wrong.

Use one of following :

```js
document.getElementById("nameInput1").value = "";

document.getElementByClass("reset").value = "";
```