# Internet Explorer 11 issues: addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js

I am trying to add listener event for mouse down on a list of elements. The code works for chrome, but not for IE

```
document.getElementsByClassName('select2-result-selectable').forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { console.log( "User clicked on 'foo.'" ); 
  e.preventDefault();}); 
})
```

This works on chrome, but not on IE 11.

I tried the following code as well.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('select2-result-selectable').forEach(function(item){
    if (item.addEventListener){
        item.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){ console.log(e); e.preventDefault(); 
        console.log( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );}) 
      } else if (item.attachEvent){
        item.attachEvent('mousedown',function(e){ console.log(e); e.preventDefault(); 
        console.log( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );})
      }
    })
```

But this was again futile, it works for chrome, but not on IE. Any suggestions?

Comment: When running into trouble with code in IE11, always be sure to use F12 to open the dev tools so you can see what specific errors it's giving you. In this case, for instance, I suspect the error isn't about `addEventListener` at all, but rather `forEach` on `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: I'm in favor of T.J. Crowder's opinion. How does it not work for IE? What is the specific error showing in console in IE? I run your code in IE and Chrome, neither works. Have you tried the solution in T.J. Crowder's answer? I test it and it works well in both IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you'll find that it's not `addEventListener` that's the problem, although your second code block would have needed `onmousedown` rather than just `mousedown` in the `attachEvent` call (Microsoft used the "on" prefix on event names). But IE11 has `addEventListener` anyway, it would only be missing if IE11 were hobbling itself (which you can fix by adding the `X-UA-Compatible` header to your page in `head`):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

...and turning off "compatibility view" for Intranet sites if necessary.

**But**, I think the problem is that you're trying to use `forEach` on an `HTMLCollection`. The return value of `getElementsByClassName` **isn't** an array, it's an `HTMLCollection`. The spec doesn't require `HTMLCollection` to have `forEach` (Chrome adds it as an extension). `forEach` is defined for `NodeList` (the type returned by `querySelectorAll`), but not `HTMLCollection`, and that addition is relatively new and not supported in IE.

So to use `forEach`, you'd do:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('select2-result-selectable', function(item) {
    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, you can polyfill `forEach` on `HTMLCollection` easily, though, as shown in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929259/157247). Here's a loop doing both `NodeList` (if necessary) and `HTMLCollection` (if necessary), and polyfilling `forEach` (if necessary) and (for browsers that have it) `Symbol.iterator` (IE11 doesn't, though, you may choose to leave that code off although it's harmless to leave it):

```
var ctors = [typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList, typeof HTMLCollection !== "undefined" && HTMLCollection];
for (var n = 0; n < ctors.length; ++n) {
    var ctor = ctors[n];
    if (ctor && ctor.prototype && !ctor.prototype.forEach) {
        // (Yes, there's really no need for `Object.defineProperty` when doing the `forEach`)
        ctor.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
        if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.iterator && !ctor.prototype[Symbol.iterator]) {
            Object.defineProperty(ctor.prototype, Symbol.iterator, {
                value: Array.prototype[Symbol.itereator],
                writable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then your original code using `forEach` on `HTMLCollection` would work.

Comment: @MaheshMesta - Your suggested edit makes the `meta` element's content invalid. `IE=edge` is correct, not `IE11`. (You could use `IE=IE11` to pin IE11 mode, but that would be less than ideal on legacy pre-Chromium versions of Microsoft Edge.)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is using .foreach. It isn't supported in IE11

Change it for a regular for loop.

```
var myclasses = document.getElementsByClassName('select2-result-selectable')

for (var i = 0; i < myclasses.length; i++) {
   array[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { console.log( "User clicked on 'foo.'"); 
}
```

Or you can use other language processors like [babel](https://babeljs.io) to fix it and build your sites, depending on what your stack looks like.

*This is untested as I don't have access to ie11 at the moment*

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return a `NodeList`, so that link isn't relevant. `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which isn't defined to have `forEach` at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, cheers! I rapidly saw DOM on the second set down, and clumsily threw it in. Edited

Answer (score 0):

you can have a utility like below

```
 function addHandler (element, type, handler) {
  if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
  } else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent("on" + type, handler);
  } else {
    element["on" + type] = handler;
  }
 }
```

that can work on all browsers, 
In this case you should use like

```
addHandler(item, "mousedown", function() {....} )
```

Comment: IE11 has `addEventListener`. It was added in IE9.

Comment: Separately, that isn't **at all** an adequate replacement for `addEventListener`. For a fully-functional version, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799296/js-li-tag-onclick-not-working-on-ie8/23799448#23799448).