# Unable to run the following js code in IE11 or IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I've made a simple html page with some js code, i've used all vanilla JS and checked to be using all compatibile functions with IE.

The issue is that the following page runs in Google Chrome as it have to, while in IE it's not working, i've tryed in IE11 and IE9 and it's not working in both.

The code is just adding click event to three buttons, button + / - which change the quantity inside the input and the confirm button.

The js looks like this:

```
<script>
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-qty');
    const confirms = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-success');
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.qty')
    
    confirms.forEach(function(confirm) {
     confirm.addEventListener('click', confirmHandler);
    });
    
    function confirmHandler(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        let product_id = this.getAttribute("data-product-id");
        let option_id = this.getAttribute("data-option-id");
        let iva = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-iva"));
        let price = this.getAttribute("data-price");
        let qty = this.getAttribute("data-qty");
        window.location.href = "_?productId=" + product_id + "&optionId=" + option_id + "&iva=" + iva + "&price=" + price + "&qty=" + qty
    }
    
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
            let btn = input.parentNode.querySelector(".input-group-prepend").querySelector('.btn-qty');
            let confirm = input.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.btn-success')
          let curVal = parseInt(input.value)
            confirm.setAttribute('data-qty', curVal)
            if (curVal >= 1) {
             btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }else if(curVal <= 1){
             btn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
            }
        }); 
    });
    
    btns.forEach(function(btn) {
     btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let input = btn.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.qty')
        let curVal = parseInt(input.value)
        let type = btn.getAttribute("data-type");
        
        if (type == 'minus') {
            if (curVal > 1) {
                input.value = curVal - 1
                input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
            }
            if (parseInt(input.value) == 1) {
                btn.setAttribute('disabled', true)
            }
        }else if (type == 'plus'){
                input.value = curVal + 1
                input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        }
        
     });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the same code run on Chrome (top) and IE11 (bottom)

[image]

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrfdqb5n/1/) of the code

Comment: what's the error on IE9/11?

Comment: You probably have an error on the console

Comment: BTW https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088141/internet-explorer-11-issues-addeventlistener-not-working

Comment: @Berto99 the console is empty..

Comment: It's hard to figure out what is going wrong without a [mcve]. For all we know, all the `document.querySelectorAll` return empty collections.

Comment: @Ivar added the JSFiddle code in the question

Comment: @KasperJuner The console _does_ give an error for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyJGz.png Check the link Berto99 provided. You can't use `.forEach` on an `HTMLCollection` (which is returned by the `querySelectorAll`). I'd just use a regular for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ivar's suggestion. We need to add polyfill for `forEach` in IE, then it can work with NodeList and HTMLCollection in IE. Please add the following polyfill:

```
var ctors = [typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList, typeof HTMLCollection !== "undefined" && HTMLCollection];
for (var n = 0; n < ctors.length; ++n) {
    var ctor = ctors[n];
    if (ctor && ctor.prototype && !ctor.prototype.forEach) {
        ctor.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
        if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.iterator && !ctor.prototype[Symbol.iterator]) {
            Object.defineProperty(ctor.prototype, Symbol.iterator, {
                value: Array.prototype[Symbol.itereator],
                writable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Besides, there's another error in this line in IE:

```
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

You need to use the following codes to use `dispatchEvent` in IE:

```
var event = document.createEvent("Event");
event.initEvent("change", false, true); 
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: i actually changed all forEach with a regulat for, is it okay anyway to use a simple for in that case?