# How to execute querySelectorAll with li elements that are less than the third child of the parent and not of a certain class?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-selectors

Say I have a `ul` as such:

```
<ul>
   <li class="good"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="good"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="good"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
   <li class="bad"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to select all the child of elements of `ul` that are less than the eighth child (so the first 7) and don't have the class `bad`.

I want to do something like `querySelectorAll('ul li:not(:nth-child(n+3)) li:not(.bad)')` Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to include text in the `li`s saying whether they should or should not be in the result you want. (Also: Your `ul` doesn't have the class `unstyled`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do the "less than 8th" with just CSS, but you can convert the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` into an array and grab just the first seven via `.slice(0, 7)`, then `filter` out the ones with the class you don't want (`bad` in your sample data I think):

```
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul.unstyled li")]
                .slice(0, 7)
                .filter(li => !li.classList.contains("bad"));
```

Live Example:

```js
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul.unstyled li")].slice(0, 7).filter(li => !li.classList.contains("bad"));

for (const li of list) {
    console.log(li.textContent);
}
```

```html
<ul class="unstyled">
   <li class="good">0</li>
   <li class="bad">1</li>
   <li class="bad">2</li>
   <li class="bad">3</li>
   <li class="bad">4</li>
   <li class="good">5</li>
   <li class="bad">6</li>
   <li class="bad">7</li>
   <li class="bad">8</li>
   <li class="bad">9</li>
   <li class="good">10</li>
   <li class="bad">11</li>
   <li class="bad">12</li>
</ul>
```

---

The above assumes that `NodeList` is iterable on your browser, as it is on most. If it isn't, but your environment supports ES2015+, you can easily polyfill it using [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929259/157247). Alternatively, use `Array.prototype.slice` directly as in this ES5 example:

```
var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(
                document.querySelectorAll("ul.unstyled li"),
                0, 7
            ).filter(function(li) { return !li.classList.contains("bad"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
document.querySelectorAll("ul li:not(:nth-child(n+8)):not(.bad)");
```